# Error-prone in Gradle multi-module project

Tags: gradle, errorprone

How to enable error-prone for some modules in a multi-module Gradle project? I want to have the ability to turn on error-prone for several modules (not for all).

Answer (score 0):

You can share this build logic as a plugin in `buildSrc` and only apply this plugin to your target modules.

For example, this sample in the official website https://docs.gradle.org/current/samples/sample_convention_plugins.html has two plugins and three modules:

```gradle
├── buildSrc
│   ├── build.gradle
│   ├── settings.gradle
│   └── src
│       └── main
│           └── groovy
│               ├── myproject.java-conventions.gradle
│               └── myproject.library-conventions.gradle
├── internal-module
│   └── build.gradle
├── library-a
│   ├── build.gradle
│   └── README.md
├── library-b
│   ├── build.gradle
│   └── README.md
└── settings.gradle
```

Two of them apply the `myproject.library-conventions` and only one apply the `myproject.java-conventions` plugin:

```gradle
// internal-module/build.gradle
plugins {
    id 'myproject.java-conventions'
}

dependencies {
    // internal module dependencies
}
```

```gradle
// library-a/build.gradle
plugins {
    id 'myproject.library-conventions'
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':internal-module')
}
```

```gradle
// library-b/build.gradle
plugins {
    id 'myproject.library-conventions'
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':internal-module')
}
```